how to maximize the lightning flexi page screen to fit the components in to that partciular area
HTML:
<template>
    <lightning-card >         
                <div class="float-container">              
                <div class="float-child">   
                <img src={salesforceLogoUrl}  class="img_deg" />
                </div>              
                <div class="float-child">  
            <div class="set-width">
            <lightning-input type="text" value={name} label="UserName"   onchange={handleName} ></lightning-input>            
            <lightning-input type="password" value={exp}  label="password"   onchange={handleExp} ></lightning-input>
            <lightning-button label="Login" onclick={validate}  ></lightning-button>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Forgot Password</a>
            </div>
        </div > 
            </div>
</lightning-card>    
</template>

CSS:
.set-width {
    width: 50%;
}

.img_deg
{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
.float-container {
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}

.float-child {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}  


you want your components to take 100% width in the flexipage area you are placing it in?

I tried your given code, and implemented slds-grid in order to format and adjust the height and width. Slds-grid allows you to adjust the columns in the html itself and also eliminates the use of custom CSS
<template>
   <lightning-card >
      <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-p-left_xx-small">
         <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 ">
            <!-- <img src={salesforceLogoUrl}  class="img_deg" /> -->
            <span> sample image</span>
         </div>
         <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 ">
            <span >
               <lightning-input class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2" type="text" value="UserName" label="UserName"   ></lightning-input>
               <lightning-input class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2 slds-p-bottom_xx-small" type="password" value="UserName" label="password"    ></lightning-input>
               <lightning-button class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1" label="Login" onclick={validate}  ></lightning-button>
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Forgot Password</a>
            </span>
         </div >
      </div>
   </lightning-card>
</template>

Here is the formatted output

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)
